# Does anyone create some personalized Ubuntu WebApps Userscript following the walkthrough posted on the Bazaar directory of the project?

Tags: webapps

I'm beggining to read the walkthrough to create to userscript to use with greasemonkey and ubuntu webapps, and I'm wondering if there's a post or a directory which centralized all those scripts that could be very interesting to use.

It could be useful to avoid to recreate the same webapps too many times.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://launchpad.net/webapps-applications). The userscripts are in `src/`.